# CSS - Two different hover colors on a table

Tags: css, colors, highlight

I've got a table that I'm using for a check list. For a collection.

Basically what I'm looking for is a way to have the table hover color GREEN if it's an item I own, and red, if its an item I don't

I'm very new to CSS and I'd appreciate any help if possible.

Here is my code (Messy)

```
**http://jsfiddle.net/6TYBb/1/**
```

Comment: this sounds more like you need to implement javascript along with CSS

Comment: I've been toying with it, but I'm even less familiar with JS ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two CSS classes to style the rows.

```
tr.own:hover { background: green; } 
tr.not:hover { background: red; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6TYBb/215/

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way: http://jsfiddle.net/9gmrG/

Sub Class out the td so you have owned and not owned. Then trigger them on hover.

```
tr:hover{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
tr:hover td.owned{
    background-color: green;
}
tr:hover td.notowned{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How is this table generated? You could add different classes to the table rows to indicate which hover style you wish to use. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BkmaW/

```
tr:hover {
    color: red;
}

tr.true:hover {
    color: green
}
```

edit: removed "!important", had added it without reason.

Comment: What does the !important; do?

Comment: why the !important indeed? No need for it here. It is considered bad practice and should only be used when all other options fail. Your code will become a hell to maintain if you use it to lightly!

Comment: It's not needed, I'm not sure why I put it in actually as the .true would already overwrite the default hover.

@level42, !important will cause the selected style to be used over other any other style, regardless of its specificity.